# How to track in-app-purchases like Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have recently tried Firebase and it is tracking `in-app-purchases` well. I am looking to implement similar feature so that my library can track in-app-purchases as well, but not able to find much hints to begin with. The [API doc](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html) does not disclose any method so that a library can track in-app-purchase without making App's Activities extend my custom Activity.

Please help if someone knows how to track in-app-purchases from library without intercepting Activity's implementation.

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.

Comment: I just wanted the link to be present here, reverted it for some reason. Hope you understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching on web and reference documents only solution, I am able to figure out is to create a `Base Activity` in your library and in `onActivityResult` process the `transaction details` and finally app's `activities` need to extend libraries base activity.

If anyone gets a better answer, just comment or answer here and I would love to accept that.